# Create one common blacklist that applies to all campaigns in Google AdWords

Tags: google-ads, ip-address, block

We are currently creating an IP exclusion list for each campaign separately in Google AdWords.   Is it possible to instead  have one common list for all of my campaigns?

Is it possible to make exclusions not by IP but by AS (Autonomous System - IP range) completely?

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, this must be done on a campaign by campaign basis.

While still tedious because it needs to be done for each campaign, if not already using the Google Ads editor, you could use it to make the campaign edits and then upload/push the campaign changes all in one go, rather than trawling through the Google Ads interface campaign, by campaign.
[Google Ads Editor](https://ads.google.com/home/tools/ads-editor/)